# Openshift 'oc rsync' fails because of vanished files

Tags: openshift, rsync

In Openshift 3.9, when I use 'oc rsync' to export jenkins data from my jenkins pod to the host's file system, I get the following error:

*rsync warning: some files vanished before they could be transferred (code 24) at main.c(1650) [generator=3.1.2]
error: exit status 24*

This seems to be a known issue with the underlying linux rsync utility and has a [workaround](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86879/suppress-rsync-warning-some-files-vanished-before-they-could-be-transferred). However, because the rsync utility is called by 'oc' in my case, I cannot figure out how to deal with this issue.

Suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Like `rsync`, `oc rsync` seems to have a `--exclude` option that is also described in your [workaround](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86879/suppress-rsync-warning-some-files-vanished-before-they-could-be-transferred).

So using `--exclude` should allow you to exclude the folder with the ephemeral files:

```
oc rsync --exclude='/path/to/*/tmp/' POD:/remote/dir/ ./local/dir
```

Comment: The problem seems to happen with different types of files located in different folders under the jenkins data folder. Files can include log files, config history and temp files. So, it's not obvious to determine what files to exclude.

Comment: You can specify multiple exclude paths, should you find the patterns do do so. But otherwise you may have to think about another solution, such as using an external PV that you can access.